# Formatting text in VS Code signature suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building an extension for VS Code and I'm wondering how to format text that I provide through `SignatureHelp` for a signature suggestion. In other extensions I see that you can at least make the text italic or bold and I haven't had any luck looking in repos to figure out how they do it.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by putting the parameters inside the ***SignatureInformation*** label (yes, it's a string and I just appended the human readable parameters at the end of my label).

I needed to provide an array of ***ParameterInformation*** containing the parameters I put in the label.

It magically worked after I provided the right ***activeParameter*** and ***activeSignature*** to the ***SignatureHelp***.

Answer (score 0):

VS code supports Markdown formatting in various places, e.g. hovers (very similar what you can use here or on Github, e.g. `**` for bold `_` for italic etc.).

Comment: I've tried using this and unless I'm doing something completely wrong it doesn't seem like it works for function signature suggestions.

Comment: Well, I haven't used that particularly for function signatures, but for others like [hovers](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/providers/HoverProvider.js#L23). Maybe markdown is not enable for function signatures (especially as they may use normal syntax highlighting)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done based on extensions like the one for C# has the active parameter bold and underlined. I cloned the repo for that extension, built and debugged it, but didn't see anything besides the actual text for the function and parameters being returned by the signature suggestion provider. I must be missing something small here.